# ls -l numbers between the size and the group

Tags: ls

when I run `ls -l /dev/null /dev/zero /dev/tty` I get:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Aug  9 09:05 /dev/null
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty  5, 0 Aug  9 09:05 /dev/tty
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 5 Aug  9 09:05 /dev/zero
```

what do the numbers 1 and 5 (after the group) indicate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those files are special files called **devices**.

They don't have a size parameter, but two number called **major** and **minor** number.

Major is somehow related to type of device (terminal, disks, network interface, filesystems).

Minor is related instance number.

I use the word "related", you simply do not count, different disk might have different major number. Computing of this two value is complex, and is mostly done by your OS.

- HP-UX use `insf -e` to create those device
- Solaris use `devfsadm -c disk` for disk
- AIX use `cfgadm -a` (from memory)

EDIT:

**b)** you seldom have a use for those number, as I mention misceleanous utilities manage them for you. 
 **a)** you mostly cannot manualy compute those number. You know them or not. I use them only once, in HP-UX 11Iv1, volume group creation involve using `mknod /dev/vgX c 64 0x010000` , 64 being major and 0X010000 being minor. It was user responsabilities to manage minor number.

Comment: Thanks. Two comment - a. I don't understand your last paragraph - what do you mean by `I use word related`, and `you simply do not count`? b. what are these numbers used for?